# Is there any way to float TabPage of TabControl?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having TabControl in which there are multiple tabs. I need to have a functionality in which if I 'drag a tab' or 'right click on tab -> float' then that tab comes out from tabs list and becomes free float window(or a winform) which can be moved anywhere on the screen. And vice Versa.

Here is the code for the TabControl-

```
TabControl tabControl = new TabControl();
TabPage tabPage1 = new TabPage();    
tabPage1.Text = "Tab Page 1";
TabPage tabPage2 = new TabPage();
tabPage2.Text = "Tab Page 2";
tabControl.Controls(tabPage1);
tabControl.Controls(tabPage2);
```

Comment: Not possible directly. Instead of TabPages design UserControls and add those to the Tab control. Then you can float them by removing it from the page, deleting the page and adding it e.g. to the form, another form or whatever.. - Much better than using any sort of Panels as you now can use the Designer. Note that you need to create suitable propeerties to acces the fnctionality. Which is a good thing, if a little tedious..

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for swaping Tab-Page controls to Form and vise-versa. Please note that instead of adding controls to Tab-Page, you need to first add controls in a panel and then that panel need to be added to the Tab_Page:

```
   private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TabPage tabPage1 = (TabPage) sender;

        Form frm = new Form();
        frm.Text = tabPage1.Text;

        Panel panel = (Panel) tabPage1.Controls[0];
        tabPage1.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        tabControl.TabPages.Remove(tabPage1);

        frm.Controls.Add(panel);
        frm.Show();

    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form frm = (Form) sender;
        TabPage tabPage1 = new TabPage();

        tabPage1.Text = frm.Text;

        Panel panel = (Panel)frm.Controls[0];
        frm.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage1);

        frm.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        frm.Hide();

    }
```